# Turn off ALL hyphenation in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, hyphenation

This seems like something that should be easy to do... but I'm stuck, today, needing to use Illustrator. And desperately want to turn off ALL hyphenation.

How do I do this? There's no switch, seemingly, to do it.

And I don't fancy entering the entire dictionary into the exceptions panel in preferences.

Comment: `Window > Type > Paragraph` and at the bottom of the window `Hyphenate (checkbox)`. All new text boxes you create will use this setting (unless overwritten by a style), though when you make a new document, it defaults to hyphenate again. Another way would be to have it in your Paragraph Style: `Window > Type > Paragraph style` → `Paragraph style options > Hyphenation > Hyphenate (checkbox)`.

Comment: @Joonas that should probably be an aswer ;)

Comment: @joonas, I completely agree with joojaa, that's an answer! Which begs a question... why is it there, and not in the preferences?

Comment: @joojaa, is there somewhere I can ask about other's experiences with the new Illustrator? It's mind bendingly stuttery and laggy for me, on a crisp new Macbook Pro. I have VERY low expectations for Illustrator performance on a Mac, but it's getting ridiculous, and far beyond bothersome. Have switched to using Affinity Designer, despite it only being half baked, at best... stuck with Macbook Pro, and no Bootcamp, for a few days... and REALLY missing CorelDraw for quick things I need to show and explain. INFURIATION at all time highs.

Comment: @Confused, the Hyphenate option has lived in the paragraph panel going back to, at least, the original Creative Suite.  If your Illustrator is running unexpectedly slow, try un-ticking the GPU performance box in `Illustrator preferences > GPU Performance`.  You can find a list of system requirements for optimal GPU Performance [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/system-requirements.html#main-pars_minitoc).

Answer (score 3):

Open up the **Paragraph** Menu. Click the 3 Horizontal Lines (Menu) on the right hand side, then click on **Hyphenation**.

**Unclick** the **Hyphenation** option. Done.

Alternatively you can also set the ***Words Longer Than*** option to something large like 15 letters, and nothing will be hyphenated.

Comment: Welcome Neil! Thanks for supplying an answer. Please don't litter answers with irrelevant links - especially given your chosen username. If you wish to promote your web site, you can do that in your profile, not in questions or answers.

Comment: Hi Neil. For more information on self-promotion on the Stack Exchange Network, please see [this help center page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).